# Удаленный рабочий стол c debian

Tags: debian, rdp

Появилась необходимость в удаленном рабочем столе, желательно **debian 9** и где нибудь в Европе.
Поиски в интернете выдают VPS, но там ни слова про GUI, а мне нужен именно с граф. интерфейсом.
Нужно через **Remmina** подключаться и чтобы все было как говорится из коробки.

Comment: Не знаю как вам объяснить, но если просто то обычный компьютер на базе debian с графическим интерфейсом. И чтобы можно было к нему подключаться удаленно. Как то так

Comment: Хочу пользоваться как вторым ПК в поездках, допустим подключаться через планшет, либо с других ПК. Так как некоторые программы есть только там, да и привык уже - собственно и нужен дебиан. И еще, понимаете - у меня есть сервис, где на связи нужно быть постоянно, собственно на многих мессенджерах. Постоянно ПК держать работающим не очень хочется, а вот подключиться к удаленному рабочему столу - намного удобнее

Comment: А кто мешает на VPS поднять XWindows и настроить DE по вашему вкусу, ну и удаленый доступ?

Comment: Мешает некомпетентность в данном вопросе :) В общем я думаю что все понял, спасибо всем, буду пробовать!

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае можно на VDS поднять linux с графическим окружением и использовать сервер/клиент например `nomachine.com/ru` для проброса рабочего стола.

Answer (score 0):

Cудя по всему, вы не знаете как называется пакет, который надо поставить для того, чтобы на машине установился `x-server`, какой-нибудь *display manager*, какой-нибудь *window manager* и т. д. и т. п.

В дистрибутиве *debian gnu/linux* такой пакет называется `task-desktop`:

```
$ apt-cache show task-desktop
...
Description-en: Debian desktop environment
 This task package is used to install the Debian desktop.
...
```

Просто установите его (это приведёт к установке сотен пакетов по зависимостям), и получите «gnome desktop» (по умолчанию):

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install task-desktop
```

Comment: Это делается на VPS?

Comment: это делается на том компьютере, где вам нужны все эти «x-server, какой-нибудь display manager и т.д.». если этот компьютер называется «VPS», то — да, «это делается на VPS».

Answer (score 0):

Пробовал SPICE (протокол), не из коробки, но ощущения позитивные.

Делать на уровне x-server-на-x-client -- не очень -- сервер отвалился, программы закрылись. Да и трафик больше.

Разные VNC -- настроить просто, но мелкие баги видны были.